# Corda node health check in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, corda

i have written a compose file that will also start some APIs that depend on an RPC connection to a corda node.

how can i use the health check function of docker compose to only run the api once the rpc connection is ready?

```
  corda-node:
    image: corda/corda-zulu-java1.8-4.4
    healthcheck:
      test: [DONT KNOW WHAT GOES HERE]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    ports:
      - 10002
      - 10003
      - 10004
      - 2223

  api:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: APIDockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - corda-node
```

Answer (score 0):

so this isn't exactly a Corda question so much as it is a question of how you want to implement health checking from the container to the service itself.

Take a look at this simple example:

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
  interval: 10s
  timeout: 5s
  retries: 5
```

source: Peter Evans - https://github.com/peter-evans/docker-compose-healthcheck

You can see in this example that there are multiple retries and a large timeout with 10 second intervals until postgres is ready.

I'd think about maybe using curl and just ping an endpoint on a Corda spring boot server that you attach to your cordapp.

Best of luck!